# Check if every row of column is within range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am building some unit tests of data and am having trouble writing a pythonic check of data.

I have a pandas `DataFrame`:

```
d = {'one' : pd.Series([.14, .52, 1.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
     'two' : pd.Series([.57, .25, .33, .98], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Now, I want to verify that these columns have data that falls within the range [0,1]. I'd want a function:

```
check_data(df, column)
```

that just returns `True` if the data does fall in the range and `False` if it doesn't. So in my example data, `check_data(df, 'one')` returns `False`, `check_data(df, 'two')` returns `True`.

My head is trying to take on a row by row approach (thank my years of Excel VBA), but I know that's wrong. Anyone got a better approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `between` and `all` to check individual columns:

```
>>> df['one'].between(0, 1).all()
False
>>> df['two'].between(0, 1).all()
True
```

`between` includes the endpoints by default; to change this set `inclusive=False`.

You could also check every column of the DataFrame at once if you wished:

```
>>> ((0 <= df) & (df <= 1)).all()
one    False
two     True
dtype: bool
```